# Pivot table counting blank cells in formula error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

This problem bugs me every year and every year I can't remember how to fix it!

My data is fine, but my pivot table reads it wrong.  My IF statement says that if the code is PP or PA, to count this and put in a 1, if not, to leave it blank.  The pivot table then sometimes displays this correctly:
[PP has a 1, SA does not.  This is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM0pp.png)

but sometimes it does not:
[Here, SA and NBC have a 1.  They should not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHV2E.png)

Why is this?  Why? Why? Why?
What can I do to have them all count correctly?  I think I seem to remember that is is something about secret characters hidden in the cells or formatting or something. Please help.

Comment: you need to share the data going into the pivot not just the output

Comment: Seeing the if statement might help.

Comment: Hi Peter, The data is just 1 or nothing.  I have now 'cleaned' my data with Trim, but now it is worse.  Instead of some cells being counted and some not, now every single cell is counted whether it has a 1 in it or nothing.  Before, it was hit and miss.  So i suppose I am making some progress but now it is all wrong!

Comment: Sorry Justin,  I think I have confused saying it was an IF statement.  I just used that to get the correct data = 1 or nothing.  I then copied and pasted the results as just Values into a new sheet.  So I have no formulae at all in my new sheet.  All values.  Then I base my pivot table on that but it is counting all cells in that column as positive.  I have just used trim and code to check for elusive characters, removed some, all now shiny and clean, but now the pivot table counts all as positive, not just random ones.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have worked it out!!! And it is just stupid.

1. Ensure that your blank cells are actually blank.  Use TRIM to clean off any leading spaces (when you copy and paste values from one sheet to another, it puts in a space where there was a formula that returned no result).
2. Check they are blank. Use CODE to check the result of the cells.  If they really are empty, the CODE check will return #VALUE.
3. Right, so you think this has cured the problem, right? Wrong!  Don't ask me why, but you have to then do the following:
4. In all of the empty cells, you must type in a character (Use Find and Replace for this). Put in a character that you are not using elsewhere e.g. ZZZ, and enter.
5. Go do Find and Replace again and delete all of those ZZZ's.
6. Now refresh your pivot table and Voila! It works!!!

What a load of hassle!